# Como puedo hacer una transición entre np array a xarray dataset?

Tags: python, array, numpy

Tengo un conjunto de datos llamados seismic_data cargados con la librería xarray como un dataset, y estoy buscando corresponder los datos de seismic_data con los valores predispuestos para seismictrace (ii,jj) con el mismo dataset. Adjunto código de como seria con np array:

```
    xls=[]
    ils=[]
    for i in range (0, seismic_data.shape[1], grid_step):
           xls.append(i)
    for i in range (0, seismic_data.shape[2], grid_step):
    ils.append(i)
grid=[]
for ii in xls:
    for jj in ils:
        seismictrace=seismic_data[:, ii, jj]
        nnz_total=np.count_nonzero(seismictrace)
        
        if seismictrace.any() and nnz_total>0:
            trace=[ii, jj]
            grid.append(trace)
```

Con xarray dataset seria asi:

```
    xls=[]
    ils=[]
    for i in range (0, seismic_data.dims['xline'], grid_step):
        xls.append(i)
    for i in range (0, seismic_data.dims['iline'], grid_step):
        ils.append(i)
    grid=[]

            seismictrace=seismic_data.sel(twt=seismic_data.twt[:],
                                          xline=seismic_data.xline[0,seismic_data.dims['xline'],grid_step],
                                          iline=seismic_data.iline[0,seismic_data.dims['iline'],grid_step])
            nnz_total=np.count_nonzero(seismictrace.values)
    for ii in xls:
        for jj in ils:
            if seismictrace.any() and nnz_total>0:
                trace=[ii, jj]
                grid.append(trace)
```

Quiero que haga lo mismo que en el código de np array pero no lo logro con la línea de seismictrace en xarray. Si alguien tiene un comentario o sugerencia lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de seleccionar una sola traza con `seismic_data.sel()`, puedes usar la indexación de xarray para seleccionar todas las trazas correspondientes a los índices `ii` y `jj` de tu bucle `for`. Puedes hacer esto de la siguiente manera:

```
for ii in xls:
    for jj in ils:
        seismictrace = seismic_data.isel(xline=ii, iline=jj)
        nnz_total = np.count_nonzero(seismictrace.values)
        
        if seismictrace.any() and nnz_total > 0:
            trace = [ii, jj]
            grid.append(trace)
```

La función `isel()` de xarray te permite seleccionar un subconjunto del dataset utilizando índices enteros en lugar de etiquetas. En este caso, usamos los índices `ii` y `jj` para seleccionar una sola traza. La propiedad `.values` se usa para obtener los valores de la traza seleccionada como un array NumPy.

Ten en cuenta que también deberás ajustar el bucle `for` que define las listas xls e ils, para que se base en las dimensiones `xline` e `iline` del dataset.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! diste en el clavo!